# MTSQL Rollup joined tables error

Tags: mysql

I have a parent table generic_Catalog with a primary key
"PART-Number

It is linked to a child table "Drop_Material" using "Part-NUMBER
as the foreign key. DROP_Material has may records with the 
same "PART-NUMBER"

I join the tables together to get information from the generic_catalog
for discription information on the part

When I use the WITH ROLLUP function to get a grand total I get

Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'infrastructure.gc.material_desc' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

If I do not have the rollup function I do not get an error

```
select 
gc.generic_Part_number,
gc.material_desc as Discription,
gc.material_Cost_est,
 sum(dm.qty)
from generic_catalog as gc

left Join drop_material as dm on 
gc.generic_Part_number = dm.generic_catalog_generic_Part_number

where dm.Wall_Drop_Wall_rooms_Residence_residence_id = 'Bacara Lot 223'
group by gc.generic_Part_number with rollup
;
```